# How to use regex using awk

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file, say *test.txt*  which looks like a json and it contains a single line of data:

```
{"a":"b"},{"c":"d, e, f"},{..} and so on
```

I need to save all the data within each pair of braces in a different file in separate lines.

For eg: *result.txt*  having

```
"a":"b"
"c":"d, e, f"
```

I used awk with regex in bash scripting

```
awk '/\{(.*?)\}/' test.txt  > result.txt
```

But instead of cropping up individual braces, it's printing the exact test file as it is.

Can anyone say what's going wrong?

Comment: _looks like a json_ or an _actual JSON_?

Comment: It is actually a json response to a query to extract the properties of a certain page. I saved it in the txt file to sort out the values. I know I should use a json parser but I tried doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '{"a":"b"},{"c":"d e f"},{..}' |awk -v RS="{|}" '{gsub(/,/,"")} /./{print $0}'
"a":"b"
"c":"d e f"
..
```

Note: It's a good idea to use `json` editing tools like `jq` to play around with json files.

Comment: It does work on the console. But when I try to assign the result to a file, the results don't seem to appear in new lines.

Comment: Its working for me . try `echo bla bla bla | grep -oP '{\K.*?[^}]+'` as alternate solution

Comment: @Kritzii: That is the exactly the problem of using text processing tools which rely on `regEx` in one way or the other, the slightest change in `JSON` formatting like an extra space will screw everything up

Comment: In total agreement with Inian. however, I am running over old Linux box which do not have `jq` and cannot get it due to some management reasons (not is my control ) then people have to search for alternatives. Reiterating , getting `jq` is best solution if possible.

Comment: Thanks @PS , the code worked. I have used Jackson parser before. I just tried working with awk as I am new to scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use `grep` with lookarounds to capture only the value between curly braces:

```
grep -oP '(?<={).*?(?=})' test.txt > result.txt
```